# ionic android icon not same original size/ratio

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a simple 1024x1024 icon.png under `resources/` :

[image]

Then i run ionic resources and all the icons i need are generated under `resources/android/icon/`

My config.xml is changed to this:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
```

Now if i look at the app icon once installed it looks like the figure in the middle is bigger and ratio is not respected:

[image]

As you can see, the little red ball became a huge ball, this is something i don't understand, can anybody clarify me this?

Answer (score 4):

(Can't place comments yet, so I'll do it by answering)

By the looks of it you're using an iconpack of some sort. (Since all the icons have the same shaped background with the original icon on top). My guess is that the icon pack eliminates most of the transparent space surrounding your icon (and all others), to fit the same icon design.

You can easily find out if this is indeed the case by either:

- disabling the iconpack (the red circle should be normal sized now, with the surrounding whitespace)
- making an icon with a border around the sides of the icon, so it probably won't cut off the whitespace.

If it is indeed the iconpack that's eliminating the surrounding whitespace, you could try to have a very light (99% transparent) layer as a background. This will prevent the iconpack from eliminating whitespace, so it won't scale the circle.

I wouldn't really recommend this though, since most people won't use an icon pack and then the icon could look a little strange on other devices.

Comment: Hi, thank you but  what you mean by icon pack? @G.deWit

Comment: i use a 1024x1024 .png then run ```ionic resources``` and all the icons are created and config.xml is populated, what else should i do ? sorry i don't understand at the moment ...

Comment: An icon pack is often used to unify the look of different icons. In Android there are no real limitations (only guidelines) on how icons should look. This often results in a bit of a chaotic look. To make icons look more or less the same icon packs where created. So in your case, it's very likely that the icon pack on that Android phone, changes the icons a bit, in order to make them more or less the same.

Comment: So the ionic preset pack is not correct? I tryed using a 99% opacity background but the red circle looks the same of the screenshot :(

Comment: I don't think it's an iconic issue. The icon pack is probably installed on the phone. What phone are you using and do you happen to have an other one to test your icon on?

Comment: I have a huawei p8 lite and a old android 4.1 tablet i may try same icons on the tablet too but i guess that wouldn't be much, since android devices are millions types :/ , how do you setup icons for cordova android usually?

Comment: As far as setting up icons (for Cordova) you're not doing it wrong. I'm sure it's a thing with the icon pack the P8 uses. You can however install a different launcher. (It's a homescreen replacement app, Google it) Nova launcher is a good one. By default it doesn't apply a icon pack, so you will see your icon without any changes made to it.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is because of the `ionic resources` command. It will read the image and auto crop the image depend on each screen size.

[Ionic Resource Site](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html) said that `no rounded corners` maybe It's for non-transparent pixels outside the main picture, or it will resize/crop it to fit:

> The icon image’s minimum dimensions should be 192x192 px, and should have no rounded corners.

You can try this:

- Navigate to the `project\resources\android\icon`:

  - Check if every icon in was generated wrong ratio.
  - If it is bigger than your's original image, open up any picture editor like `Photoshop` or `Paint` and resize it manually by hand until fit your expected ratio (because you should only need the `ionic resources` generate the pre-sized picture).
  - Save and do it again for the others.
  - Rebuild the project.

**UPDATE:** Put 4 tiny pixel of color for 4 corners and try again. I think the device should know where is the correct border for the icon instead of resizing it.
[image]

Comment: already tried doesn't work, looks like the device removes trasparent sides and resize the figure to fit the icon at 100% width :(

Comment: So sad, but I have this option for you: try again with my steps, but you should put 4 small pixel of color from 4 corners (top-left, top-right, bot-left, bot-right) at the border. This may let the device know where is the border of your icon.

Comment: @sbaaaang did you give it a try yet?

Comment: actually it's a problem because to use this trick as well as a few opacity background i have to use at least 20% opacity and this is s**t :/ because you will se it on the device icon :/ i really guess no solutions